# Сколько битов информации может передаваться за 1 такт

Tags: передача-данных, теория

Частота работы устройства - это количество операций в секунду, и если каналов (шин) много, то за один такт можно обрабатывать много бит. А вот например при передаче данных, там один кабель, и я говорю, что за такт можно передать 1 бит информации, а ребята говорят что можно и 2,3,..32 битов.

Скажите пожалуйста **сколько битов информации может передаваться за 1 такт**, и если их больше одного, как это возможно???

Comment: А что такое один такт?

Comment: А что такое "один кабель". в кабеле то проводов много может быть ... И тег "база-данных" какое отношение имеет к вопросу. Да, и "такт" чего у вас в кабеле

Answer (score 7):

Передать можно ровно столько, сколько позволяет алгоритм кодирования. Понятное дело, что когда мы опускаемся до физического уровня, то по проводу никто не передает 1 и 0. Там сигнал кодируют. Самое простое кодирование, которое применяют, это следующее. 0 кодируется 0-1, а 1 кодируется как 1-0 (1 - есть напряжение, ноль - нет). Почему не просто  1 и 0? а это для того, что бы избежать ситуции, когда передается много нулей или единиц. Понятно, что в этом случае на один "виртуальный такт" будет передано один  бит (или даже пол бита, смотря как сделана схема).

А можно передать 2 бита за "такт"? (я беру слово "такт" в кавычки, потому что низком уровне оно требует уточнения. И наверно правильнее говорить "передать бит за один раз") Оказывается можно.  Для этого будет использовать не просто "есть сигнал-нет сигнала", а будем использовать амплитудную модуляцию. Грубо говоря, 00 - ноль вольт, 01 - 1 вольт, 10 - в вольта и 11 - 3 вольта. Да, эта система будет неустойчива к длинным сериям нулей или единиц, но суть передает. Понятное дело, что можно таким образом передавать и 3 бита. Главное, на приемной стороне иметь настроенный [ацп](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%87), что бы он мог точно декодировать. Самое интересное, эту методику используют в современных [ssd](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C). В нем каждая ячейка - это маленький конденсатор. И различным напряжением в нем кодируются биты. MLC использует 2 бита на ячейку, TLC - 3 бита.

Можно ли передать ещё больше? да, конечно. Есть различные методики кодирования. Например, [QAM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Модификация QAM-16 позволяет передавать 4 бита за раз, а QAM-256 - 8 бит. И эти методы кодирования реально используются в приемо-передающей технике. Но вот объяснить, как они работают - это уже за пределами данного поста и тянет на один-два курса технического вуза по специальности "системы передачи в радио технике".

Comment: Можно подробнее, что означает "0 кодируется 0-1"?

Comment: Ну и в большинстве современных стандартов все таки не напряжением  определяется бит, а направлением тока (что бы избежать помех и добиться высоких скоростей).

Comment: 0 кодируется как "нет сигнала - есть сигнал", а 1 кодируется как "есть сигнал-нет сигнала".

О "направлении тока" не слышал. А добиться высоких скоростей позволяют правильные алгоритмы кодирования+алгоритмы восстановления ошибок (например, код Рида-Соломона)

Comment: Все равно не понял, вот допустим два единичных бита, что мы имеем на линии? (есть сигнал, нет сигнала, ???, есть сигнал, нет сигнала)

Comment: два нулевых бита - на линии имеем нет сигнала-есть сигнал-нет сигнала-есть сигнал.

Comment: ну а второй переход как отличить от "есть-сигнал/нет сигнала" ? Т.е. от единицы. Если по отдельному тактовому сигналу, то к чему тогда городить эти переходы и не ограничиться просто уровнем 0/1 ?

Comment: Частота передачи сигнала известна. Есть специальные сигналы синхронизации. Если помните старые модемы, которые работали от обычного проводного телефона, то при подключении он интересно "шипел-свистел". Вот это как раз и есть тот момент, когда модемы договариваются о алгоритмах кодирования и синхронизируются.

Answer (score 2):

Объем сигнала определяется тремя параметрами: V = FTD. Здесь F - ширина спектра сигнала, T - длительность сигнала и D - динамический диапазон (логарифм отношения сигнал/шум, упрощенно его можно считать числом различимых уровней сигнала).

Сколько информации закодировано в сигнале - зависит от модуляции, но объем сигнала ограничивает количество информации сверху.

Если поделить эту формулу на время - получится формула максимальной пропускной канала связи, ширина спектра умноженная на динамический диапазон. С практической стороны, эта формула обозначает следующее:

**За то же самое время можно передать в два раза больше бит если использовать в два раза большую полосу или в два раза больше уровней сигнала.**

Если подходить "в лоб", то первый способ не поможет передать два бита за такт - потому что при увеличении частоты длительность такта уменьшается. Но можно наложить друг на друга два разных сигнала, разнеся их по частотам - в таком случае длительность такта окажется прежней, а пропускная способность возрастет.

Comment: **при увеличении частоты длительность такта обычно уменьшается** как бы частота умножить на длительность такта  равно 1, или что то поменялось?

Comment: @KoVadim Можно увеличить частоту несущей без увеличения частоты сигнала, тогда длительность такта меняться не будет.

Comment: @KoVadim но если вас расстраивает слово "обычно" - убрал его